# Cypress does not store value for the global variable?

Tags: cypress

I have a cypress code like this. When it is run, the 'result 1' has the value but the 'result 2' doesn't.
My question is : cypress will store the value inside its block only ? How could I store value for 'result 2' ? I'm quite new with cypress. Thanks for your help

```
it('My function', function()
{        
        var tkname =''
        cy.get('tr:nth-child(1) td:nth-child(3) div div div div p').then(coiname =>
        {
             tkname = Cypress.$(coiname).text()   
             //result 1
             cy.log(tkname)    
        })
        //result 2
        cy.log(tkname)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

The commands are async, so you need to access inside a `.then()` at the point `// result 2`.

```js
const tkname =''

cy.get('tr:nth-child(1) td:nth-child(3) div div div div p').then(coiname => {
  tkname = coiname.text()   
  //result 1
  cy.log(tkname)    
})
.then(() => {
  //result 2
  cy.log(tkname)
})

cy.log(tkname)  // this log already used the value of tkname, 
                // but it's still empty at this point
```

Because of that requirement, there's no need for the "global" variable, you can return the value from the first `then()` and it will be passed on.

```js
cy.get('tr:nth-child(1) td:nth-child(3) div div div div p').then(coiname => {
  return coiname.text()   
})
.then(tkname => {
  cy.log(tkname)
})
```

Cypress also has aliasing to set a kind of global value, but it's still accessed inside a `.then()`

```js
cy.get('tr:nth-child(1) td:nth-child(3) div div div div p').then(coiname => {
  cy.wrap(coiname.text())
    .as('tkname')           // alias to use value anywhere in the same test
})

cy.get('@tkname').then(tkname => {
  cy.log(tkname)
})
```